# How to find out position of clicked element?

Tags: jquery, click, position

How do I find out, in what position a list item was clicked.

So, let's say I clicked the second list item:

```
<li><a href="#"><span>Tab 2</span></a></li>
```

Then, I would get an alert saying something like:

You clicked the second list item?

**JQuery Code**

```
$('#top-betting ul li:first').addClass('current');
$('#top-betting div:not(:first)').hide();

$('#top-betting ul li span').click(function()
{
    ...?
});
```

**Markup**

```
<div id="tabs">
   <ul class="clearfix">
      <li><a href="#"><span>Tab 1</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Tab 2</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Tab 3</span></a></li>
   </ul>

   <div>Content 1</div>
   <div>Content 2</div>
   <div>Content 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) like this:

```
$('#top-betting ul li span').click(function() {
   var index = $(this).closest('li').index();
});
```

Overall, [I think this is what you're after](http://jsfiddle.net/P32Rn/):

```
$('#top-betting ul li span').click(function() {
    $("#top-betting div").eq($(this).closest('li').index()).show()
                         .siblings('div').hide();
});​
```

Comment: Bingo, thanks Nick. I can't accept it for another 10 minutes yet

Answer (score 2):

`index` is the method you're after.

```
$('li a').click(function(e){
        var $li = $(this).parents('li');
        var $ul = $(this).parents('ul');
        alert($ul.children().index($li));
    });
```

Check the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9V9D2/

Comment: There's no need for all that, `$(this).closest('li').index()` works :) `.index()` with no arguments gets the index of the element with respect to its siblings.

Comment: Thanks, just saw your answer. I must say index() is the one jQuery method that gives me most problems.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`index` method](http://api.jquery.com/index/).