# How to get position of the clicked element

Tags: jquery, html

I have a button, after user click a search form will be displayed over it.
Form is placed at the bottom inside footer.

I need to get button position (absolute, left, top).

This is my `html` entry:

```
<div><button class="search-button" type="button">Search<button></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find out position of clicked element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159301/how-to-find-out-position-of-clicked-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $(function() {
     $("#search-button").click(function() {
         var $clicker = $(this);
         var pos = $clicker.position();
         console.log(pos.top);
         console.log(pos.left);
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give the position of the button.

```
 $(button).offset()
```